# Using 2 input csv files, and comparing them

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have two functions that receive one csv file each, like this

```
def cars(file_one):
    with open(file_one, 'rU') as car_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(car_file, delimiter=';')
    result = []
    for line in reader:
        result.append(line)
return result
```

The other one does the same thing as this one but for the owners.
Output for the cars function is this one:

```
[{'Age': '8', 'Brand': 'Ford'}, {'Age': '57', 'Brand': 'Cadillac'}, {'Age': '2', 'Brand': 'Dodge'}]
```

For the owners function:

```
[{'Owner': 'Trevor', 'Brand': 'Ford'}, {'Owner': 'Bob', 'Brand': 'Cadillac'}, {'Owner': 'Trevor', 'Brand': 'Dodge'}]
```

Now I have a third function that compares the two lists and returns this:

```
[{'Owner': 'Trevor', 'Average_Car_Age': '5'}, {'Owner': 'Bob', 'Average_Car_Age': '57'}]
```

And I have two problems first of all how do I call the 2 functions and use them on the third one since I need the csv files as parameters when I do this:

```
def final_list(cars, owners)
```

and use something like final_list('cars.csv', 'owners.csv') this doesn't work.

My second problem is just comparing the two lists, I'm not being able to do so.
if someone can help me out I would appreciate.

edit: my input is a simple csv file that I did with Excel:

```
Brand;Age
Cadillac;57
Ford;8
Dodge;2
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a sample of your input.

Comment: Give me a second. I will @DisplayName

Comment: What is the third function looking like currently?

Comment: @LucasMoeskops My third function doesn't have anything atm since i couldn't make it work so i started re-writing it again, i just need to have an out put that gives me a new list of dicts with the output that i said ealier.

Comment: *"(...)  how do I call the 2 functions and use them on the third one (...) ?"* `final_list(cars('cars.csv'), owners('owners.csv'))`

Comment: @jDo I tried that but without the 'cars.csv' part so i could run it with any other file name. ty

Comment: @EXT I thought you had two CSV files, two functions meant to parse these CSV files and return lists of dictionaries, and a third function that takes two lists of dictionaries and compares them

Comment: @jDo Yes you are right, but i managed to do the 'calling the function in another function' part work i just need to compare de 2 lists of dict from the functions an get the output i want.